# how to keep call the function all time when mouse stop above a div?

Tags: jquery

if the mouse stop above a `div` I need call a specific function, but I need call it all time..

I've tried `.mouseover()` and `.hover()` but these work just when the mouse is moving

how keep call the function all time???

Comment: What do you mean by all the time? Every second? Every millisecond? Immediately after it returns? You probably don't want to make your user's CPU catch on fire - why do you think you need this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setInterval` function allows you to arrange for a function to be called repeatedly according to a fixed schedule:

```
var intervalKey = setInterval(yourFunction, milliseconds);
```

The "milliseconds" value tells the system how long to wait between calls. The cycle can be cancelled by calling

```
clearInterval(intervalKey);
```

What you would do would be to set a flag on the "mouseover" event, and then clear the flag in the "mouseout" handler. The "mouseover" handler would also start the interval timer.  The timer function would check the flag to determine whether it should stop (flag no longer set), and cancel itself.

Answer (score 0):

`.hover()` works for me whenever the mouse is hovering.  It doesn't have to keep moving. Just tried it for 2 minutes no problem. Nothing [mentioned here](http://api.jquery.com/hover/).

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to keep firing the same function. this would be murder on the client's processor. maybe a timeout and recheck?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to track the mouse movement within the box, you'll need to use `mousemove()` rather than `mouseover()` or `hover()`.

See a good example here: http://www.lbstone.com/reference/jquery/follow_mouse.html

If you want exactly what you asked for in the question -- ie continually firing the same function over and over while the mouse is over a div, you'll still need `hover()` or `mouseover()`, but when they fire, you'll need to call `setTimeout()` to start the repeating function, and within that function, check if the mouse is still in the `<div>` and if so, repeat the `setTimeout()` call. (alternatively, use `setInterval()` to start the sequence and `clearInterval()` to stop it; same end result)

It's quite a complex operation (and fraught with possible issues), so I'd avoid doing it if at all possible. What is it that you're trying to achieve by doing this (there's a very good chance theres a better way to do it! ;-))